# how can i actualise my timer at each seconds on react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i try to learn React JS and i don't understand how is functionning the "main function', i did a timer who gives me the date and the hour but it actualize the timer only when i write something on my searchbox.

There is my code:

```
return (
    <div className="app">
     
<main>
      
        <div className="search-box">
          <input
          type="text"
          className="search-bar"
          placeholder="Search..."
        
          onChange={e =>setQuery(e.target.value)}
          value = {query}
          onKeyPress={search}
          />
          
        </div>
        <div className="location">
            {weather.temp}
        </div>
        <div className="location">
              {new Date().toLocaleString() + ''}
        </div>

        </main>
   
    <div>
      
    </div>
    </div>
    
  
  );
}

export default App;
```

it only actualize the date when i press my keys in my form. I'm totally new in JS so i think i missunderstand something.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Please read up https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html 
The React team has a great doc. I am sure you'd be able to figure it out once you go through this. It's plain and loaded with examples to understand concepts.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we've more context for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for yout answer with the documentation, it helped me

Answer (score 1):

I think part of your code is missing here, anyway, if you are new I recommend you to stick to hooks.
useState https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html and useEffect
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i followed the documentation and it works

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one of the timer functions supplied by the JavaScript host environment, such as `setInterval` or `setTimeout`.

The following code configures a React component `Clock` that updates itself every second using a `setInterval` timer.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

const Clock = (props) => {
    const {initialHours = '--', initialMinutes = '--', initialSeconds = '--', initialTimezoneOffset = ''} = props;
    const [hours, setHours] = useState(initialHours);
    const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(initialMinutes);
    const [seconds, setSeconds] =  useState(initialSeconds);
    const [timezoneOffset, setTimezoneOffset] =  useState(initialTimezoneOffset);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
      const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        const now = new Date
        const timezoneOffset = -now.getTimezoneOffset()/60
        setHours(now.getHours())
        setMinutes(String(now.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0'))
        setSeconds(String(now.getSeconds()).padStart(2, '0'))
        setTimezoneOffset(`${timezoneOffset >= 0 ? '+' : '-'}${timezoneOffset}`)
      }, 1000)
    
      return ()=> {
        clearInterval(intervalId)
      }
    })

    return (
      <div>{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds} UTC{timezoneOffset}</div>
    )
}



ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock/>,
  document.querySelector('main')
)
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Courier;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main></main>
```